# Домен для почты

Tags: веб-программирование, домен, email

Есть домен для сайта, который уже присоединён к хостингу. Как и где сделать домен для почты? Предположим, сайт **[example.com](http://example.com)**. Хотелось, чтобы было вот так **support@example.com**.

Answer (score 3):

Мало того, что в самом домене (у регистратора) такая возможность обычно существует, а при наличии хостинга - и подавно! Смотрите внимательнее - там всё есть!

Comment: мне всегда было удобнее делать это на хостинге, обычно там и доходчивая инструкция есть.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать почту для домена от яндекса. Подробнее можете посмотреть в Яндекс.Вебмастер.

Answer (score 1):

Да можно и google использовать.

Обычно почта создается из панели управления хостингом. Что за хостинг у вас?

Answer (score 1):

Если есть зарегистрированный домен, для почты нужно поднять только сервис  (postfix, exim)и добавить правильные MX-records. Создать почтовый ящик для пользователя "support" - это уже просто.

Answer (score 0):

можно так:

1. создать почтовый ящик на яндексе.
2. добавить к нему свой домен https://pdd.yandex.ru/domains_add/
3. и создать ящик для своего домена.

профит.